# Pointer operant issue with iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

If I have the class Rectangle

```
Class rectangle{
    //attribute
    ....

    //methods
    ...
    void getInfo() const;
}
```

And main

```
int main(){
    vector<Rectangle> v;
    for (vector<Rectangle>::const_iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end(); ++it){
        it->getInfo();
    }
}
```

why

```
"it->getInfo();"
```

returns me right value about all vector contents and

```
"*it->getInfo();"
```

return me an error?

i learned that iterators are like pointer.. and for take its content you should deference it..

Comment: `->` is a dereference operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why
>
> "it->getInfo();"
>
> returns me right value about all vector contents

`it` is an iterator.  An iterator can be dereferenced to access the item it refers to, and both `operator*` and `operator->` are acceptable ways to dereference an iterator.  `it->getInfo()` is the same as `(*it).getInfo()`.

> and
>
> "*it->getInfo();"
>
> return me an error?

`operator->` has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator*`, so the expression above is evaluated as if it had been written as `*(it->getInfo())`, which fails since `getInfo()` does not return a type that can be dereferenced with `operator*`.

Even if the compiler evaluated it the other way, `(*it)->getInfo()` would also fail since `rectangle` does not have an overloaded `operator->`.

> i learned that iterators are like pointer..

LIKE pointers, but not guaranteed to BE pointers.  All pointers are iterators, but not all iterators are pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
it->getInfo();
```

is correct because; iterator and -> is dereferencing it.

```
*it->getInfo(); incorrect

(*it).getINfo();
```

in Short, -> is a shortcut to  (*it).getINfo(); in term of writing and it is better to read.

Comment: "*iterator is a pointer*" - not always. But iterators are designed to imitate pointers, so many pointer operations can also be applied to iterators

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to dereference a pointer, one is by `*`, and one by `->`, where the latter must be followed by a data member or member function associated with the static type of the pointee. Example:

```
void doStuff(const Rectangle&); 

Rectangle rect{/* ... */};
Rectangle *pointer = &rect;

doStuff(*pointer); // dereference the pointer

const double width = pointer->width(); // dereference and use a width() member function
```

The same applies to iterators, where these operators are overloaded. In your case,

```
it->getInfo();
//^^ dereference the iterator
```

does the dereferencing by `operator ->`, while `*it->getInfo()` tries to dereference the return type of `getInfo()`, which is `void`. By the way, `getInfo()` for a member function returning `void` is a confusing name, you might to overthink that. And let me plug a second suggestion here: the loop can be simplified by range based for loop like this:

```
for (const Rectangle& rect : v) {
    rect.getInfo();
}
```

Note that the loop variable `rect` is a `const`-qualfied reference, and not an iterator anymore - hence, no need to dereference anything.